# On click of readmore then the remaining lines should display in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Hi Friends when i click read more link then the remaining text should be visible.
here fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y7onmxxz/1/

i refer to this link:http://jsfiddle.net/PBfDa/
here all the time they get id and making it visible, and that too it will not work for more than one,

```
<a href="#">Readmore</a>
```

any solutions please.

Comment: I get your question but where is angular ? What do you want ?

Comment: On click of that read more the remaining text should be display, but without adding class or id for the remaining text.

Comment: https://github.com/andoulla/Read-More-Directive try out this

Comment: That code demo is not working pankajparkar.  i downloaded and run it, but not working

Comment: Try Using **ng-show**

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Plunkr , simple solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>posed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default<a href="#" ng-click="show=!show">READ MORE...</a> 
  </p>
  <p ng-show="show">
    model tent here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text</p>
</body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/3ZV4ZTpyWn9vEYKGcbsE?p=preview

Comment: thanks but if i use more than one paragraph tag and click readmore then both will open. so there is issue in that. and if i click readmore that readmore button also should go right.  katmanco

Comment: Hello Manoi , it is just a demonstration , say that you have a few paragraphs in ng-repeat , then you can give all your p tags **IDs** based on ng-repeat's  $index attribute , then you can make this visibility Ok for all P tags.

Answer (score 0):

MAnoi Check This Plunkr , edited for your requirements .

```
...
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/3ZV4ZTpyWn9vEYKGcbsE?p=preview

Comment: yeah! but when i click read more that clicked read more alone get hide and that paragraph should be continue.. the remaining content should not come from the next line. @katmanco

Comment: My friend it is a simple css issue  you can handle it yourself :) and If you found my posts valuable, a positive vote would be great:)